# Glide.js api issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I am creating a slider using Glide.js plugin. I did everything like is said in documentation. In html i have:

```
<div class="slider" id="paintSlider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide paint">
                    <span><img src="img/glowna_tlo.jpg" alt=""></span>
                </li>
                <li class="slide paint">
                    <span><img src="img/paint6.jpg" alt=""></span>
                </li>
                <li class="slide paint">
                    <span><img src="img/paint3.jpg" alt=""></span>
                </li>
                <li class="slide paint">
                    <span><img src="img/paint2.jpg" alt=""></span>
                </li>
                <li class="slide paint">
                    <span><img src="img/paint5.jpg" alt=""></span>
                </li>
                <li class="slide paint">
                    <span><img src="img/paint4.jpg" alt=""></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and i have a code in script.js

```
$(function() {
$('#paintSlider').glide({
    autoplay : false,
    hoverpause : false,
    navigation : false,
    arrowRightText : '',
    arrowLeftText : '',
    circular : true

});
});
```

i have to click on the image on slider to resize it to full size, and i did it, but to do this i had to create slider api:

```
var glide = $('#paintSlider').glide().data('api_glide');

$(".lupaHolder a").click(function(){
    var slide = glide.current();
    var Src = $('li.slide.paint:nth-child(' + slide + ')').find("img").attr("src");
    $(this).attr({
        "href" : Src,
        "data-lightbox" : Src
     });

});
```

and here starts my problem; when i created an api, autoplay which were at first "false" doesn't work, and slider do autoplay. i don't know how to stop it. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got it.

All i did was rewrite to api all options what i wrote in function and then deleted this function.

like:

```
var glide = $('#paintSlider').glide({autoplay : 0,
    hoverpause : false,
    navigation : false,
    arrowRightText : '',
    arrowLeftText : '',
    circular : true
    }).data('api_glide');
```

and delete this:

```
(function() {
$('#paintSlider').glide({
    autoplay : 0,
    hoverpause : false,
    navigation : false,
    arrowRightText : '',
    arrowLeftText : '',
    circular : true,
    afterInit:function(){console.log("paintSlider")}

 });
});
```

and it works